# Перестали вноситься или выбираться нужные записи в БД

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Делаю приложение Windows Forms C# + MSSQL Server. Есть форма, которая имеет textBox'ы и comboBox'ы, в которые пользователь вносит данные о заявке, клиенте, принимаемом в ремонт оборудовании. Все поля и комбобоксы привязаны к БД на MSSQL Server, реализованы выпадающие списки по ключевым полям. При нажатии на кнопку ОК выполняются запросы на вставку введенных данных в БД и запрос на выборку id последней внесенной записи о заявке, это нужно чтобы внести данные оборудования по этой заявке.
Сначала все работало корректно, но потом добавила в MSSQL триггер и запросы перестали работать через WinForms. Очень странная проблема, не могу понять что не так. Запросы работают в MSSQL, но через приложение запрос то вносит данные в таблицу Заявка, то не вносит, запрос на вставку в табл Оборудование вообще перестал вносить данные, а запрос на получение id последней записи в таблице Заявка перестал выдавать этот id, выдает предпоследний. Думала дело в триггере, может как то конфликтуют обращения к бд и триггер, но и удаляла его и блокировала, не помогло. Таблицы БД не привожу, тк мне кажется проблема не в этом, тк запросы рабочие.
**Код C# с запросами к БД**

```C#
private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //переменные с данными заявки
            string str_typeOrderId = typeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int typeOrderId = Convert.ToInt32(str_typeOrderId);

            string str_viewOrderId = viewComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int viewOrderId = Convert.ToInt32(str_viewOrderId);

            string str_clientId = surnameComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int clientId = Convert.ToInt32(str_clientId);

            string str_employeeId = employeeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(str_employeeId);

            //переменные с данными оборудования
            string str_typeEId = typeEComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int typeEId = Convert.ToInt32(str_typeEId);

            string str_serialNum = serialNumTextBox.Text;
            textBox2.Text = str_serialNum;

            string str_modelId = modelComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int modelId = Convert.ToInt32(str_modelId);

            string str_brandId = brandComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int brandId = Convert.ToInt32(str_brandId);

            DataBase DB = new DataBase();
            DB.openConnection();
            //команда для вставки данных в БД
            SqlCommand inputOrder = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Заявка (Код_клиента, Код_сотрудника, Код_типа_ремонта, Код_вида_ремонта) VALUES (@clientId, @employeeId, @typeOrderId, @viewOrderId );", DB.getConnection());
            inputOrder.Parameters.Add("@clientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = clientId;//добавляем переменную в запрос
            inputOrder.Parameters.Add("@employeeId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = employeeId;
            inputOrder.Parameters.Add("@typeOrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = typeOrderId;
            inputOrder.Parameters.Add("@viewOrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = viewOrderId;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.InsertCommand = inputOrder;

            //Выборка id последней заявки
            **Этот запрос перестал выводить id последней записи, будто ее не видит**
            SqlCommand selectId = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Код_заявки FROM Заявка ORDER BY Код_заявки DESC;", DB.getConnection());
            SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter2.SelectCommand = selectId;
            textBox3.Text = selectId.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            int selectOrderId = Convert.ToInt32(selectId.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            SqlCommand inputE = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Оборудование (Серийный_номер, Код_заявки, Код_типа, Код_производителя, Код_модели) VALUES (@sNum, @OrderId, @typeEId, @brandId, @modelId );", DB.getConnection());
            inputE.Parameters.Add("@sNum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = str_serialNum;
            inputE.Parameters.Add("@OrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = selectOrderId;
            inputE.Parameters.Add("@typeEId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = typeEId;
            inputE.Parameters.Add("@brandId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = brandId;
            inputE.Parameters.Add("@modelId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = modelId;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter3 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter3.InsertCommand = inputE;

            if (inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 && inputE.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1) //если запрос выполнен успешно
                MessageBox.Show("Запрос выполнен");
            else MessageBox.Show("Что то не так");

            DB.closeConnection();

        }
```

**Сам Триггер:**

```DDL
USE ServiceCenter_DB;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Тригер_Выполнение1
ON Заявка
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Выполнение (Код_заявки, Код_статуса, Дата) VALUES ((SELECT Код_заявки FROM inserted), (SELECT Код_статуса FROM Статус WHERE Статус='Принята'), (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
    PRINT 'Вставка в таблицу Выполнение выполнена'

END
```

**Класс DataBase**

```C#
class DataBase
    {
        //подключение к БД
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-1LS12TNR\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ServiceCenter_DB; Integrated Security=True");
        //метод, открывающий соединение с БД
        public void openConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
        }
        //метод, закрывающий соединение с БД
        public void closeConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
        //метод, возвращающий соединение
        public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            return connection;
        }

    }
```

Уже не знаю, что не так, очень странная проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так.
Если совершается запрос на вставку записи в табл Заявка, то она отображается в самой БД и отображается в DataGridView, после этого вставляется запись в табл Оборудование,этот запрос вообще будто не срабатывает, но программа не выводит ошибок, и записи нет БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Этот запрос перестал выводить id последней записи, будто ее не видит

Он и не может ее видеть, так как Вы еще не вызвали `inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

---

И зачем эти три адаптера? Уберите их.

---

```
if (inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 && inputE.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
```

В какой ситуации результат этих запросов не будет равен единице?

---

```
...
inputOrder.Parameters.Add("@viewOrderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = viewOrderId;

inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCommand selectId = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Код_заявки FROM Заявка ORDER BY Код_заявки DESC;", DB.getConnection());
//SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
//adapter2.SelectCommand = selectId;
int selectOrderId = Convert.ToInt32(selectId.ExecuteScalar());
textBox3.Text = selectOrderId.ToString();

...

if (/*inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 && */inputE.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
  ...
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее по поводу inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery()? перед какими строками нужно добавить? Был один адаптер, добавила три, тк перестало все корректно работать... думала поможет..

Comment: До этого было без inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery() и все работало...

Comment: @Юлия Хорошо. Приведите код, который "работал" без `inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: это он и есть, я тут ошибки не вижу, поэтому ничего не меняла. Только добавила три адаптера вместо одного.

Comment: @Юлия Меняли. Или оно не работало (как Вы думали) с самого начала.

Comment: Добавила inputOrder.ExecuteNonQuery(), не помогло. В таблицу Заявка вносятся данные, но все также не выводится последнее id, хотя запись внеслась и не вносится запись в таблицу Оборудование. До этого все работало с этим же кодом...

Comment: может быть, но вообще я проверяла, в переменную заносился нужный id. Подскажите, как можно исправить?

Comment: @Юлия Вы не перекомпилировали код.

Comment: пересобрала, не помогло.

Comment: @Юлия Не может быть.

Comment: адаптер вообще не нужно использовать для выполнения запросов?

Comment: @Юлия вообще не нужно

Comment: да, все же помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @Юлия Пожалуйста. Успехов. "Галочка" - слева от ответа.